# How to change Style attribute of a div at runtime using watirwebdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have a div and the height of which is very less. I am not able to access some of the child elements which are way at the bottom of the div. I tried to scroll using
 `element .elements.last.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view`, and I was not able to scroll it.

I then tried to see if I can increase the height of the div so that the script can view all the nodes. The original style is `style = 'overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;width:150px;height: 350px;`

The code I am using to modify it is

```
element = @browser.div(:id => 'div:d')
puts element.attribute_value('style')
script = "return arguments[0].style = 'overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;width:150px;height: 750px; '"
@browser.execute_script(script, element)
puts "edited height"
puts element.attribute_value('style')
```

I still see the style value as `overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;width:150px;height: 350px;`. 
Is it not possible to edit the height of the div during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

It looks like the `arguments[0].style =` is not cross-browser compatible. When I ran your code using Firefox, the height was updated. In contrast, when running in Chrome, the height was not updated.

This difference is mentioned on the Mozilla developer page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style):

> Except in Opera, styles can *not* be set by assigning a string to the
>   (read only) style property, as in elt.style = "color: blue;". This is
>   because the style attribute returns a  CSSStyleDeclaration object.
>   Instead, you can set style properties like this:

**Solution**

To change the style attribute value, you are better off using the `setAttribute` method:

```
script = "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;width:150px;height:750px;')"
```

However, given that you only want to change the height, you could simply do:

```
script = "arguments[0].style.height = '750px';"
```

Comment: `script = "arguments[0].style.height = '750px';" ` works perfectly fine~!Thank you so much!